# Заполнить yновый массив наибольшими значениями

Tags: javascript, массивы

Подскажите как решить такую проблему
Есть массив [0,1,0,3,2], нужно написать функцию, которая ищет самое большое число в данном массиве и заполняет этим числом новый массив, пока не появится число больше и т д
т. е. результат должен быть таким
[0,0,1,1,3]
Заранее спасибо!

Comment: почему результат 0 0 1 1 3 ?

Comment: Так, а что у вас не получается? Вы не можете найти наибольшее число? Пройтись циклом и на каждой итерации сравнивать элемент с числом в заранее заданной переменной. Если больше, то складывать это число в переменную

Comment: Это я понимаю, но надо искать самое большое число слева и заполнять массив им пока не найдется чиcло больше. Массивы должны получится одинаковые, а у меня получается только массив из  нескольких чисел(которые больше пред )

Comment: например есть массив [1,1,3,1], то должно получиться [1,1,1,3]

Comment: а у меня просто 3

Comment: а почему в примере в вопросе итог 00113 а не 00123?

Comment: Добавь код в вопрос

Comment: @АлексейШиманский Потому что новое значение начинает влиять на следующий элемент и так далее. "Я так думаю."

Comment: да, надо смотреть только левые значения

Comment: let arr = [3,9,8,4,5,2];
 function testArr(){
  let answers = [];
  for(let i=1; i<= arr.length; i++){
   if (arr[i] > arr[i-1]) {
    answers.push(i);
    }
  }
  return answers;
 }

Comment: так тоже не получается

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```js
const a1 = [0, 1, 0, 3, 2];
const a2 = [a1[0], a1[0]];

for (let i = 1; i < a1.length - 1; i++) {
  a2.push(a1[i] > a2[i]? a1[i] : a2[i]);
}

console.log(JSON.stringify(a2));
```

Comment: спасибо огромное

Comment: @DDD123 Пожалуйста. Успехов.